# Filling in a data frame column based on a named vector

Tags: r

I have two vectors, one of which I've used to name the other

```
vector <- c("Apple","Banana","Cucumber","Durian")

name <- c("A","B","C","D")

names(vector) <- name
```

and I have a data frame that I am filling in

```
df <- data.frame("Fruit" = c("Banana","Durian","Apple","Cucumber"),
                 "Price" = c("$4.00", "$2.00","$1.50","$1.00"))
```

I'd like to create a third column, "label", that will fill in based on the names in the **vector**. Would look like this

```
     Fruit Price Label
1   Banana $4.00  B 
2   Durian $2.00  D
3    Apple $1.50  A
4 Cucumber $1.00  C
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated! (Anything using tidyverse would be helpful!)

Comment: side note: if the price data is numeric, then it's good to store it as numeric data. You can use `readr::parse_number(df$Price)` to convert your price column into a vector of numbers instead of strings

Comment: This was just for a quick example, but good advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dplyr`](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/):

```
library(dplyr)

vector <- c("Apple","Banana","Cucumber","Durian")
name <- c("A","B","C","D")
names(vector) <- name
df <- data.frame("Fruit" = c("Banana","Durian","Apple","Cucumber"),
                 "Price" = c("$4.00", "$2.00","$1.50","$1.00"))
df <- df %>%
  left_join(data.frame(Fruit = vector, Label = names(vector)), by = "Fruit")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     Fruit Price Label
1   Banana $4.00     B
2   Durian $2.00     D
3    Apple $1.50     A
4 Cucumber $1.00     C
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R:

```
df$Label <- names(vector)[match(df$Fruit, vector)]
```

`match()` finds the index of the `Fruit` variable in vector, and then we get that element from names(vector).

Using tidyverse, you could use the same code, just replace `df$Fruit` with `Fruit`.